# PHP - Remove last char in while

Tags: php, char

i know many function to remove char in php. but i'm confused to remove this :
 i want remove "," from

```
<?php
include '../config/settings.php';
$query = "SELECT keyword,count(*) AS jumlah 
FROM search GROUP BY keyword ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$data= "['$row[keyword]', $row[jumlah]],<br>";
echo $data;}
?>
```

will give result :

```
['Smartfren', 1],
['Telkomsel', 1],
```

i want the output like :

```
['Smartfren', 1],
['Telkomsel', 1]
```

How to do that?

big thanks for the response.

**UPDATE**

based on @orangpill answer say i have printed data like :

```
['ABC',   6597],
['XYZ',   4479],
['PQR',   2075],
['Others', 450]
```

i want to make a chart, say the code of js chart have to be like :

```
data: [
                ['Firefox',   45.0],
                ['IE',       26.8],
                {
                    name: 'Chrome',
                    y: 12.8,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                },
                ['Safari',    8.5],
                ['Opera',     6.2],
                ['Others',   0.7]
            ]
```

based on @orangepill now my code :

```
  <?php
    include '../config/settings.php';
    $query = "SELECT keyword,count(*) AS jumlah 
    FROM search GROUP BY keyword ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $data = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $data[] = "['$row[keyword]', $row[jumlah]]";
}

echo implode(",<br/>", $data);
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Presentase Sentimen Positif'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
                    percentageDecimals: 1
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            color: '#000000',
                            connectorColor: '#000000',
                            formatter: function() {
                                return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ Math.round(this.percentage) +' %';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: 'Nilai',
                    data: [


    <?php     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $data[] = "['$row[keyword]', $row[jumlah]]";
    }

    echo implode(",<br/>", $data); ?>
                    ]
                }]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might make sense for you to do this by building an array and imploding it when you want to output

```
<?php
include '../config/settings.php';
$query = "SELECT keyword,count(*) AS jumlah 
FROM search GROUP BY keyword ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $data[] = "['$row[keyword]', $row[jumlah]]";
}

echo implode(",<br/>", $data);
?>
```

If you are formatting for this data for consumption by javascript a better approach would be to use json_encode.

```
<?php
include '../config/settings.php';
$query = "SELECT keyword,count(*) AS jumlah 
FROM search GROUP BY keyword ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $data[] = array($row[keyword], (int)$row[jumlah]);
}

echo "var data =  ".json_encode($data).";";
?>
```

Comment: also ... it looks like you are trying to build json.... if that is the case look into json_encode

Comment: hi @orangepill, can you see my update? i have one problem know

Comment: Look at my updated answer again...especially the assignment.. you shouldn't assign a string you should be assigning an array. And also when you are echoing out remove the [ and ] from arround the php code block

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function:

```
$data = "";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data .= "['$row[keyword]', $row[jumlah]],<br>";
}
$data = substr($data, 0, -5);
echo $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

rtrim():

```
$data = rtrim($data, ',');
```

or, in your particular example, substr:

```
$data = substr($data, 0, -5);
```

to remove the "
" as well.

Comment: Run it after your loop.

Comment: Orangepill's answer is much more efficient than mine.

Comment: @Orangepill, ah right. List of characters. substr($string,0,-5); would work, but yours is still the better answer.